# Check property value of CSS element, and use resulting true or false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and wish to check the property value of the element (below it is whether Lodagema_Desc is visible or not). I understand that I should probably be applying this a boolean variable here but I'm not entirely sure how. I wish to check whether that is true or false (see "if vis=true").

Practically, I'm trying to animate a div, that will wipe across the page and become visible after clicking on the `prio_img`. Afterwards, I want to have the same animation basically in reverse from clicking on `prio_img` again.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#prio_img").click(function() {
        var vis = $("#Lodagema_Desc").is(":visible");
        if (!vis){
             $('#Lodagema_Desc').css({visibility: "visible"}).animate({ 
                width: "1110px", //changes to visible, then animates to the correct width
             }, 800 );}
        else{
            $('#Lodagema_Desc').animate({
                width: "0px",
            }, 800).css({visiblity: "hidden"});
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: I've fixed the syntax errors, but there are still issues with the code.

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error in the Javascript console?

Comment: if (vis=false) and try

Comment: @swetha That's already in both answers.

Comment: Use toggle. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/yZk5S/1/

Comment: @Barmar Yes I was. It was waving a big error flag in the corner but I didn't look at it because it always says I have errors (something about document not being defined). I should have checked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/yZk5S/5/

Try this

```
var $img = $('img'),
    originalWidth = $img.width();

//Set height
$img.height($img.height());

$('a').click(function(){
    $img.animate({ width: $img.width() == originalWidth ? 0 : originalWidth });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had the toggle function working, however from personal preference I want the Div to look like it is opening outwards to the right, across the page. Hence having the width go from 0px to 1110px and back again.

Comment: Try the above example.

Comment: Thanks this is working a lot better than the way I was doing it :)

Comment: I am glad it helped. If there is anything else, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong

Change

```
 if vis=false{
```

To

```
if (vis==false){
```

Answer (score 0):

use == not =

```
 if (vis==false){
```

or just

`if (!vis)` (for false)

Answer (score 0):

Conditions for an `if` statement need to go in brackets `()` like so:

```
if(vis) // == true
if(!vis) // == false
```

I've updated your code to fix your statement. Note, adding an `!` before the statement inverts it. I've also removed the var as you're only using it once. You might as well put the condition straight into the `if` for readibility.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prio_img").click(function() {
        // The condition reads: if Lodagema_Desc is not visible, then...
        if(!$("#Lodagema_Desc").is(":visible")){
             $('#Lodagema_Desc').css({visibility: "visible"}).animate({ 
                width: "1110px", //changes to visible, then animates to the correct width
             }, 800 );}
        else{
            $('#Lodagema_Desc').animate({
                width: "0px",
            }, 800).css({visiblity: "hidden"});
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

You can also just use `:hidden` like so (to save you inverting the original condition):

```
// This condition reads: if Lodagema_Desc is hidden, then...
if($("#Lodagema_Desc").is(":hidden")) {
    // animate in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` syntax is wrong. Also, you need to set the `vis` variable inside the function. Otherwise, it just contains the visibility when the page was loaded, not its current visibility.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prio_img").click(function() {
        var vis = $("#Lodagema_Desc").is(":visible");
        if (!vis) {
             $('#Lodagema_Desc').css({visibility: "visible"}).animate({ 
                width: "1110px", //changes to visible, then animates to the correct width
             }, 800 );
        }
        else{
            $('#Lodagema_Desc').animate({
                width: "0px",
            }, 800).css({visiblity: "hidden"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah. I didn't think about having to define inside the function, makes perfect sense. Thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition if(vis===false) is syntactically wrong and throwing a js error.
The below code works fine

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vis = $("#Lodagema_Desc").is(":visible");
    $("#prio_img").click(function() {
        if (vis===false){
            $('#Lodagema_Desc').css({visibility: "visible"}).animate({ 
                width: "1110px", //changes to visible, then animates to the correct width
            }, 800 );}
        else{
            $('#Lodagema_Desc').animate({
                width: "0px",
            }, 800).css({visiblity: "hidden"});
        }
    });
});
```